# Unable to connect using ssh from cmd

Tags: windows, ssh

Unable to connect using ssh from cmd

I have tried running the below command from the Windows cmd

```
ssh.exe user@host -o "ProxyCommand=nc -X connect -x <proxy_ip:port> %h %p"
```

I am getting the below error. What am I missing here?

> ```
> CreateProcessW failed error:2
>
> posix_spawn: No such file or directory
> ```